# no-repeat CSS radial-gradient

Tags: css, background, radial-gradients

Is there a way to not repeat the white circle ?

http://dabblet.com/gist/3136266

```
background: #ffffff;
background-image:
    radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%),
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 5px, transparent 5px),
    linear-gradient(0, rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.75) 3px, transparent 3px);
background-size:
    400px 60px,
    15px 15px,
    7px 7px;
background-position:
    1px 1px,
    -2px -2px,
    1px 1px;
```

thx for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use background-repeat the same the others

`background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat, repeat;`

Answer (score 3):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat, repeat;
```

Example: http://dabblet.com/gist/3136366